# How to make predicate for simple Prolog database

Tags: prolog

I have this database, which tells prolog who is who's friend and what that friends favourite colour is:

```
*/ has_friend(name, their friend)
has_friend(lisa, mary).
has_friend(john, peter).
has_friend(carl, erin).

*/ has_favourite_colour(their friend, colour)
has_favourite_colour(mary, red).
has_favourite_colour(peter, blue).
has_favourite_colour(erin, green).
```

What I want to do now is create a predicate "info/1" which uses the name as argument and then tells me who their friend is and what their favourite colour is. How do I do this? I basically suck at prolog and I've read 3 books and all sorts of tutorials but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Right off, `info/1` is the wrong way to go about it. You just said you wanted `info` to relate a name to a friend and their favorite color. That's 3 arguments right there, not one. So I'd suggest `info(Person, Friend, Color)` as your predicate. Then what does `info/3` mean? It means *`Friend` is a friend of `Person`, and `Person` has favorite color, `Color`*. Translate that sentence into Prolog, and that's how you implement `info(Person, Friend, Color)`. Remember, Prolog is about defining relations, not delineating tasks. A predicate `p :- s1, s2.` means `p` is true if `s1` and `s2`.

Comment: What is this `*/`?

Comment: **3** books ? come on...

Answer (score 2):

Such questions are very common among beginners. The key insight is that you want to describe a **relation** between 3 things:

1. a person
2. their friend
3. the friend's (I assume) favourite colour.

Consequently, it will be natural to use **three** arguments (not one) for such a relation.

A good predicate name helps to write down the definition in a straight-forward way:

```
person_friend_colour(Person, Friend, FriendColour) :-
        has_friend(Person, Friend),
        has_favourite_colour(Friend, FriendColour).
```

It is written here as a typical Prolog rule, i.e., of the form `Head` ← `Body`.

We can therefore read it as `Body` → `Head`, which may be a bit easier: **If** `Friend` is a friend of `Person`, **and** `FriendColour` is that friend's favourite colour, **then** it is the case that `person_friend_colour/3` holds for these three entities.

Example query:

```
?- person_friend_colour(Person, Friend, FriendColor).
Person = lisa,
Friend = mary,
FriendColor = red ;
Person = john,
Friend = peter,
FriendColor = blue ;
Person = carl,
Friend = erin,
FriendColor = green.
```

This shows all solutions there are.

To obtain natural formulations of your relations, use an adequate number of arguments!

Comment: Ah that makes so much sense. Thanks a lot!